# How to add text to foreign key field in Django

Tags: django

I am using a foreign key in Django. If the data you want to add is not in the foreign key, you want to enter it directly and save it in the db. After Googling for hours, I couldn't find a solution. Is there any way?

Comment: Plz add source code of your models and desired results

Comment: When adding data in the form, only the data of the foreign key is imported. I'm looking for a way to append by typing text directly instead of selecting given data.

Comment: Its difficult to guess what your both the models contains and what are you trying to achieve... However, your theoretical question itself contains the answer `check if the object exist with the entered text, use that object if its there else create a new object and then use that foreign key`

Comment: You can't choose the foreignkey or text in django. You have to create a foreign key object and then after a page refresh, you can attach it to the current model.